# Slow loading of TableView when I do registerNib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with following statement(s) in its initialization:

```
[self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:kDatePickerID bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kDatePickerID];
```

I notice because of this statement the tableView seems to load slow VISIBLY (relative to empty tableView loading)

Is there a way I can optimize on the above statement/issue?